# WebRTC channels and workers

Tags: webrtc, web-worker

I am interested whether it would be possible to create and transfer WebRTC data channels within and between workers. For instance, I would like to do P2P networking in service workers, but perhaps offload some communication to web workers for CPU-intensive derivatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-pc/pull/317 has not landed in the spec yet, Firefox might have implemented that already however. Your best bet is to ask in #media on irc.mozilla.org

Not going to work in ServiceWorkers however for a number of reasons.

Comment: I've come across https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-pc/issues/230. It indicates that support for workers might come in the future.